# Why does git clone not copy remote branch and give error message when git status? problem with upstream?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-status

I just created my own github page which is finalexam96.github.io

On Visual Studio Code, I did `git clone https://github.com/finalexam96/finalexam96.github.io.git`

I created an index.html file committed everything and it worked. But when I try to check it out with  `git status`, it says

> On branch main
> Your branch is based on 'origin/main', but the upstream is gone.
> (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

> nothing to commit, working tree clean

I tried to see if I have proper branches and typed `git branch` which is for local branch and it shows

> *main

Then I tried `git branch -r`, but it showed nothing. so I believe the remote branch doesn't exist.

At this point, I didn't know what to do, so I used `git remote add origin https://github.com/finalexam96/finalexam96.github.io.git` but  it returns

> error: remote origin already exists

So my remote branch exists but it won't show up when I try to see a list of remote branch.

I want to see `#of commits ahead` when I use `git status`

What should I do to make this work?

Comment: "I want to see #of commits ahead when I use git status" Well you're not going to. Your remote repository at Github is *empty.* There is nothing to be ahead of.  You have to give it initial content with your first push. That is why simple `git push` is not yet allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Use following commands to upload your commit:

```
git push origin main
```